# VHDL strange when-statement error (syntax)

Tags: syntax, vhdl

We've been having a really strange, yet simple when-statement error in our VHDL code, by now we've tried everything we could think of but the program still complains about a syntax error (near the first "when") in the statement.

```
    ALUsource <= '0';
            with FuncCode select
                    ALUcontrol <=   "10" when "0x20",
                                    "10" when "0x22",
                                    "00" when "0x24",
                                    "01" when "0x25",
                                    "11" when "0x2A",
                                    "00" when others;

            with FuncCode select
                    SubFlag <=     '1' when "0x22",
                                   '0' when others;

            with FuncCode select   
                    W_ena <=       '1' when "0x20",
                                   '1' when "0x22",
                                   '1' when "0x24",
                                   '1' when "0x25",
                                   '1' when "0x2A",
                                   '0' when others;


    when OPcode /= "000000"
            with OPcode select
                    ALUcontrol <=   "10" when "0x08",
                                    "11" when "0x0A",
                                    "00" when others;
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is at the first "when", not at the fifteenth? With no error messages and no line numbers, all anyone except you can do is ... guess.

Comment: Which statement with a `when`? No one can evaluate these selected signal assignments without seeing at least declarations (`FuncCode`, `OpCode`, `ALUcontrol`, `SubFlag` and `W_ena`).  Show us the actual and complete error message. A syntax error can sometimes require seeing the entire design unit. This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As previous comments said, this example is not complete and therefore hard to tell where the error is, but i take a guess and suggest writing

`when OPcode /= "000000" =>`

instead of

`when OPcode /= "000000"`